# Updating my graphic card firmware to latest version but my sound card disabled and won't work

Tags: graphics-card, sound-card, firmware

I have below device:

CPU: Intel 3570K
RAM: 8GB DDR3 1600
Mainboard: [ASUS P8Z77-V Deluxe](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8Z77V_DELUXE/) (with latest version of BIOS)
Power: Green 685
VGA: AMD 5970

When I changed firmware of the graphics card (AMD 5970) to latest version, my on-board sound card stopped working. I don't know how this two components are related to each other?

Please Note: I changed Windows 7 and installed all of drivers again also I refer to warranty service but they didn't help.

Here is screenshot of device manager. All of things are normal:

[image: Device Manager]

[image: Playback]

Comment: Seems to be enabled as per Device Manager. Try right-clicking the volume icon, select Playback Devices and see whether the correct output device is selected.

Comment: @Karan, I checked and added Playback Devices screenshot all of things are OK!

Comment: There's a question mark on *Other devices*, what's in there?

Comment: @gronostaj Thanks for your comment, I changed Device Manager screenshot. Now you can see detail of Other devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your sound card driver.

If it doesn't help, try the following:

- Connect your display with a DVI or VGA cable instead of HDMI
- Disable HDMI output in *Playback Devices*
- Reboot and see if it works.

If these steps will help, then your graphics driver is forwarding all audio to HDMI for some reason. Using DVI cable would be a temporary solution, maybe just turning HDMI sound off will work too. Also, check if it's possible to uninstall just the audio component of the graphics driver.

Comment: I was updated my sound driver to latest version and I changed my graphic card (AMD 5970) with GTX 295 but this two ways were ineffective. I'm hearing some noise from speakers like as "rustle or frou-frou" when Windows 7 is loading. I think this is a big bug from ASUS!

Comment: Have you uninstalled AMD drivers before switching to GTX 295? If it still doesn't work without AMD graphics and drivers, then it's probably not a AMD BIOS-related issue.

Comment: Yes, I changed Windows when I used GTX 295. My friend had the same problem with AMD 7950 and Asus P8Z77-V PRO when he updated graphic card firmware. I know 2-3 persons with the same problem.

Comment: If there's no trace of AMD and the problem persists, then it's not AMD. Maybe some other component malfunctions when performing that update, but it's not AMD - unless your computer can communicate with an unpowered and disconnected graphics card.

Comment: Right, it is not AMD problem but I think this is motherboard components problem. Really big bug for the sound section. I don't know anymore but thank you again for your time.